# Record size with a picklist

Tags: limits, record, data-storage, storage-limit

I have a custom object `My_Object`.
I have now created another object `Shadow` which has a single field `My_Object__c` which is a Lookup to `My_Object`.

When I create a `Shadow`, each record is a whopping 2 KB. My understanding is it can't be reduced.

Now suppose I add a new picklist to `Shadow` - `My_Shadow_Type`. Will that record still stay under 2 KB or will it grow further?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the KB [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318951&type=1&mode=1), custom object record size is 2 KB.

Adding a new field won't increase the size per record.
You can actually verify it by going to `Setup | Storage Usage`, you can see that **Record Count** * **2KB** roughly equals to the **Storage usage** per each custom object regardless of the number of fields in the object.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is a guide, e.g. if i add a LTA field with 32000 limit, that is definitely more than 2 Kb per record, and i can add ~800 of those in Enterprise. Likewise, since my picklist values are capped at 255 chars, if i add 10 of those picklists, i will go above 2Kb. All that article guarantees, really, is that you can't go BELOW 2 Kb. So the question is `is it because 2 Kb are always reserved` or is it because `2Kb is mandatory overhead`. Because in first case one picklist won't go over that, and in the second it would

Comment: I am not sure how it works internally. But I tried creating a long text field with 32KB size and create a record, fill the field up to its capacity, and then clone this rec by 1000x. Storage usage is still Number of Records * 2KB.

Comment: Was your field filled up with random text or..? I imagine they compress it so if say you used a single character to fill that string then zipped it would be just a handful of bytes

Comment: I generated it from lipsum.com and truncate to match the text field size. So I believe it should be pretty random.